# How to download a file with in a folder in s3 using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am having a use case where i need to check all the sub folders in S3 and download a particular file into temp of lambda which is present with in the folder.

I was using this for downloading the file which is not with in any folder.

```
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.download_file('sumanth-bsig-test', '2022.02.11_at_22.03.11_radar-mi_5354_sec_4989385772_5092940872.bsig', '/tmp/SampleFile.bsig')



s3_client.download_file('sumanth-bsig-test', '/big_data1/2022.02.11_at_22.03.11_radar-mi_5354_sec_4989385772_5092940872.bsig', '/tmp/SampleFile.bsig')
```

when ever i am using this above code to access the file with in the folder big_data1.
I am getting

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
```

I feel i am not doing it right when it comes to downloading file with in the folder.
Could anyone help me out with this.
file structure s3->
big_dat1->file

Comment: s3 has no such things as folders.  Their existence is purely an affectation of the s3 web console, and unlike an OS Filesystem extra slashes are different prefixes. Your problem might be that you put a slash at the beginning of the prefix `/big_data1/...`

Comment: Remove the `/` at the start of the Key. Use `'big_data1/...'`

Comment: I did try big_data1/ but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

First we have to create an S3 client using boto3.client(s3).

```
 import boto3

 BUCKET_NAME = 'my_s3_bucket'
 BUCKET_FILE_NAME = 'my_file.json'
 LOCAL_FILE_NAME = 'downloaded.json'
 def download_s3_file():
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.download_file(BUCKET_NAME, BUCKET_FILE_NAME, LOCAL_FILE_NAME)
```